# Multiple variables with COUNT(URL) query

Tags: php, mysql

The query below worked when it contained just one variable ($MyURL). But when I added $MySection, I started getting this error message:

**PDOStatement::bindParam() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in**...

I know how to add multiple values in a query that fetches an array, but this kind of query is confusing for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics 
WHERE URL = :MyURL AND Site = 'PX' AND Section = ':MySection' AND Live != 0";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,':MySection',$MySection,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried the following query with PDO::PARAM_STR following $MyURL, $MySection and following both of them...

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics 
WHERE URL = :MyURL AND Site = 'PX' AND Section = :MySection AND Live != 0";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':MySection',$MySection);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

But I'm getting this error message: "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Comment: if that's your actual code, there's no space after `pox_topics` and MySQL is read as `FROM pox_topicsWHERE` instead of `FROM pox_topics WHERE`

Comment: I checked the original, and there is a space between pox_topics and WHERE.

Comment: RTM on it http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php you're doing it wrong and there shouldn't be quotes around `':MySection'`

Comment: That's confusing; when I remove the quotes, I get an immediate error. It won't work without quotes around $MyURL and $MySection both.

Comment: that's not what I said, I said to remove the in => `AND Section = ':MySection'` <<<

Comment: I posted an answer below to better illustrate.

Comment: I noticed your edit. Are you sure all your bound variables have values? They are also case-sensitive. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, as outlined in my answer and make sure you've chosen the right columns and are the correct types. Use error checking also, the link's in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quotes around your 2nd bind `':MySection'` in `AND Section = ':MySection'`, those need to be removed.

Then you're using both of your binds in the same `bindParam`. They need to be on separate statements.

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics 
WHERE URL = :MyURL AND Site = 'PX' AND Section = :MySection AND Live != 0";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL);
$stmt->bindParam(':MySection',$MySection,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

Sidenote: Unsure which one you want to use `PDO::PARAM_STR` for. Adjust respectively.

Also make sure those variables have values. Error reporting will throw you something about it, should they fail.

Example from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also use PDO's error handling:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Thx for all your help. I tried your script, verified that both of my variables have values and that they're both in the database, but I'm still getting an error. I edited my post to illustrate where I am right now. I must be making a simple mistake, so I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom  You're welcome David. See if error reporting and error checking with PDO's http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php if you're not already using it.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Another thing you can try is `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` for any or all of those.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Another thing that also came to mind is that you're using `AND` in your query. If any of those should fail, then that will account for failure somewhere. Make sure the query meets "all" of the requirements. Try removing one at a time until you see it fail. You can use `OR` depending on what it is exactly you're querying for. Also keep in mind that `AND Site = 'PX'` (PX) is case-sensitive also. There could be multiple reasons as to why your query is failing. Use `var_dump();` to see what's going through or not. You are using PDO to connect with, right?

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom That's great David. What was it exactly?

Comment: I made a really dumb mistake. It turns out that after you fixed my query for me, I was getting an error message from a query in an include. It was on approximately the same line, which made it look like the original query. Oh well...

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom No worries. Remember, we're only human and everybody makes mistakes, even I make them at times. I'm glad it turned out well David, *cheers*